# How to store object inside Iterator<object>?

Tags: java, iterator

So I have a variable string and I want to store it inside an Iterator of type string, but I keep getting an error stating that it is incompatible types. How can I store a string variable inside an iterator?

```
Incompatible Types:
Required: java.util.Iterator <java.lang.String>
Found: java.lang.String
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
Iterator<?> perEntry = entries.iterator();
Iterator<String> ids;
while (perEntry.hasNext()) {
    ids = perEntry.next().getId();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

P.S. I forgot to include this, but how do I return this Iterator? I get an error stating that it found java.util.ObjectType, and it requires java.util.Iterator.

Comment: An `Iterator` is not a `Collection`. You can't store data into that. You need something like a `List` or `Set`.

Comment: Could you add the definition for `entries`?

Comment: Entries is basically a list of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood iterators. An iterator is *not* equivalent to an object in a collection being iterated. Instead, it acts like a "pointer" to such an object.

If you have `Iterator<Entity>`, you can get an `Entity` out of it by calling `next()`. However, an iterator itself would remain an iterator on `Entity`. It cannot be converted into an iterator of `String`.

However, you can harvest all strings from an iterator into a collection, like this:

```
List<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
while (perEntry.hasNext()) {
    idList.add(perEntry.next().getId());
}
```

Once you have your `idList` list filled with data, you can get its iterator. It would be an `Iterator<String>`, because `idList` element is of type `String`:

```
Iterator<String> ids = idList.iterator();
```

Comment: Thanks! But do you know how to return ids? because I keep getting java.util.List and it requires java.util.Iterator

Comment: @user3851283 What specific error do you get? What is the code that triggers it?

Comment: I added the Iterator<String> ids = idList.iterator() after the while loop and when I tried to return ids, it gives me the incompatible types error. It's requiring Iterator<string> and it found List<string>

Comment: @user3851283 This shouldn't happen: if you are returning `ids`, which is declared and initialized as an `Iterator<String>`, and your method's return type is `Iterator<String>`, there should be absolutely no type mismatch error. Please make sure that you are not trying to return `idList`. You could also do `return idList.iterator()` to make your code shorter.